# Running an application using Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to run the application [here](https://github.com/crazyfrozenpenguin/cpenguin_repository/tree/master/vert-x/eventbusTest).

I have run:

```
maven install
```

then:

```
java -cp target/eventbusTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar org.riaconnection.vertx.App
```

But then it outputs:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.riaconnection.vertx.App

Comment: If you want this to be an executable jar, have a look at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html which will bundle all classes of the dependencies in the jar.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a Vert.X app.  Try using

`vertx run ...` to run it

http://vertx.io/manual.html#running-verticles-directly

Comment: The project read me explicitly says to use maven. Vertx run does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that they have eclipse launch configuration in their repository
eventbusTest.launch file. Try to open it with Eclipse.

Or from this file sources you can find out that the main class should be

```
org.vertx.java.deploy.impl.cli.Starter
```

So this might work

```
java -cp target/eventbusTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar org.vertx.java.deploy.impl.cli.Starter
```